# Creating betting strategy for variable payout game

Tags: probability, gambling

Lets say I have a game where you choose a bet and then you and a computer choose a random multiplier.

If you guessed lower or equal to the computer, you win your bet times the multiplier you guessed.

If the computer guess is lower than yours, you lose the bet.

This graph shows the probably of you LOSING choosing a multiplier (*note*: multipliers start from 1 but there is additional 2-3% chance of computer choosing 0 and instantly winning the bet)
[image: Probability of you losing when choosing multiplier]

Now, I instantly thought about Martingale strategy, but I only found resources online that deal with fixed payouts.

How would one analyze game like this in terms of applicable strategies ?

Edit 1: The multipliers have only precision of two decimal places.

Comment: 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000.......1 unless the computer is awkward enough to lose money or waste time making no money.  Then it guarantees a gradual profit - hey it depends on the computer strategy, or what you expect it might be - if it's throwing guesses around like a googol, you can safely try a septillion

Comment: This one is a bit like the envelope paradox, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem